# Simple to do app but with different tasks in a each group(many to one relationship)

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

Main problem:
When user is at this url http://127.0.0.1:8000/8/, so  group_id is already in url of his current page, he must choose group_id that he wants to assign task, if I do `fields = ['title', completed']` in forms.py user can't choose group_id but he needs to. I have primary key but I don't know where to apply it in views

P.S.:
IndexView from views.py has no problem in it and works fine, also get method in GroupView works fine to. Anything works fine but user needs to choose a group that he want's to assign tasks

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

from .models import *


class AddTaskForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = '__all__'


class AddGroupForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = '__all__'
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Group(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views import generic
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

from .models import *
from .forms import *


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'tasks/index.html'
    form_class = AddGroupForm
    model = Group

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.groups.order_by('title')

    def get(self, request):
        self.groups = Group.objects.all().order_by('title')
        form = self.form_class(request.GET)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'groups': self.groups})

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'groups': self.groups})


class GroupView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'tasks/group.html'
    form_class = AddTaskForm
    model = Task

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.tasks.order_by('-completed', 'title')

    def get(self, request, pk):
        self.group_id = pk
        self.tasks = Group.objects.get(pk=pk).task_set.all()
        form = self.form_class(request.GET, pk)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'tasks': self.tasks})

    def post(self, request, pk):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
        form.group_id = pk
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('tasks:group', args=[pk]))
```

```
urls.py
from django.urls import path

from . import views


app_name = 'tasks'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name = 'index'),
    path('<str:pk>/', views.GroupView.as_view(), name = 'group'),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the id in the url, you may use it in the form valid method. This is the place to add information befor writing to the DB:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.group= Group.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

By the way: Your url might be `<int:pk>` (not str) as automated generated pks are integer. And you may provide a better name for your parameter. Like `<int:group_pk>`
This makes your code more readable: `self.kwargs['group_pk']`